# im looking to get the sum of all the numbers in a array

Tags: javascript

```
const sampleArray = [
  469,
  755,
  244,
  245,
  758,
  450,
  302,
  20,
  712,
  71,
  456,
  21,
  398,
  339,
  882,
  848,
  179,
  535,
  940,
  472,
];

let mainDiv15 = document.getElementById("main");
let myParagraph15 = document.createElement("p");
let myTextNode15 = document.createTextNode("KATA 16");
myParagraph15.append(myTextNode15);
mainDiv15.append(myParagraph15);
let max14 = 20;
let oneToTwentyFive15 = [];
function array7() {
  sampleArray.forEach((ix) => {
    for (ix = sampleArray; sampleArray <= sampleArray.arrayLength; sampleArray++) 
    mainDiv15.append((ix) + ", ")
  }
}
array7();
```

Here is my array and here is my function im so darn confused on how to take each element and add them together to  get a total sum. any help at all would be greatly appreaited!

Comment: `sampleArray.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)`

Comment: Do you mind showing me how ive never used .reduce and im honestly so new to this

Comment: Look at my above comment. That is how you do it.

Comment: can you explaine what .reduce does exactly please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple code is already provided in the comment section. This answer is just to make your code work.

You are using both `forEach` and inside the callback you are again using `for` which is not necessary. Both of them will do same thing. If you are using `forEach` just initialize a variable with 0 and inside the `forEach` callback add the current number under iteration with the variable.

```
let sum = 0

function array7() {
  sampleArray.forEach((ix) => {
      sum += ix;
    }
    mainDiv15.append(sum + ", ")
  }
```